# configure local (shared) memory for OpenCL using Nvidia platforms

Tags: cuda, opencl, nvidia, gpu-shared-memory

I want to optimize my local memory access pattern within my OpenCL kernel. I read at somewhere about configurable local memory. E.g. we should be able to configure which amount is used for local mem and which amount is used for automatic caching.

Also i read that the bank size can be chosen for the latest (Kepler) Nvidia hardware here:
http://www.acceleware.com/blog/maximizing-shared-memory-bandwidth-nvidia-kepler-gpus. This point seems to be very crucial for double precision value storing in local memory.

Does Nvidia provide the functionality of setting up the local memory exclusively for CUDA users? I can't find similar methods for OpenCL. So is this maybe called in a different way or does it really not exist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to control the L1 cache/local memory configuration when using OpenCL. This functionality is only provided by the CUDA runtime (via `cudaDeviceSetCacheConfig` or `cudaFuncSetCacheConfig`).

Comment: Are you sure ? any sources or something ?